# SelectOneMenu Dropdown not working well on Chrome

Tags: css, drop-down-menu, primefaces

I have this css code and I would need to adjust it such that the child and the parent dropdown menu will be align with each other. (As shown below)

[image]

The code works on IE and Firefox, but not Chrome. I need to fix the code to allow it to work on Chrome too.

Here's my CSS code:

```
.ui-selectonemenu .ui-selectonemenu-label {
background: #c9e9e2 !important;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-list {
background: #c9e9e2 !important;
box-sizing: initial !important;
padding-right: 80px !important;
text-align: left;
}

.ui-selectonemenu-item.ui-selectonemenu-list-item.ui-state-highlight {
background:#FFFFFF !important; 
text-shadow: none;
color: #444444;
 }

.selectOneMenu {
color: #444444;
font-size: 11px;
font-family: Verdana;
font-weight: 400;
height: 21px;
width: 158px !important;
}
```

Comment: can you try using `width:100%` instead of giving pixels? Do this and tell me if it helped

Comment: @anas nope it doesn't help. But the weird thing is out of all my 8 dropdown menu, only one doesn't work.

Comment: @anas I tried adding in `float: none;` into my CSS. Weirdly, it works. But after I logout from the page and login back again, that one particular dropdown doesn't work again. Firefox doesn't have this error.

Comment: then your test cases prove that the code you have done is correct this is an issue from the browser side you can google more about the css compatibility issue in chrome maybe you can find your answer there

Comment: @anas so I do not need to edit/correct my codes any further since it is correct? Okay thank you! I will google for more of the css compatibility issue

Comment: this is just my opinion as i heard it from my seniors they consider firefox to be best for development purposes chrome has some cache issues and all... if it works fine in firefox you just need to find the problem in chrome rather than on your code good luck

Answer (score 1):

I've managed to solve the problem. Now my code works in both Firefox and Google Chrome. 
What I did was by adding this few lines of code under `.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-list {`:

```
 box-sizing: inherit;
 display: inherit;
-webkit-column-width: 70px;
```

Overall, here's what my code looks like:

```
.ui-selectonemenu-panel .ui-selectonemenu-list {
background: #c9e9e2 !important;
padding-right: 80px;
text-align: left;
box-sizing: inherit;
display: inherit;
-webkit-column-width: 70px;
 }
```